# In Cognito, Developer Console: OK to Modify Google Play Game Services Entries?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-games, amazon-cognito

I have a game on Google Play that I'd like to integrate with Amazon Cognito.

This game uses Google Play Game Services, so has an entry in Google Developer Console.

I am looking at this reference document:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/devguide/identity/external-providers/google/

And trying to determine if I should add these new Credentials to the existing Google Developer Console entry (the one populated with Google Play Game Services API) or if I should create a new Google Developer Console Android application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use your existing Google Developer Console entry.

Comment: Is that how you have yours set up?

Comment: Apologies for not following up here, but I see you asked the question on our forum and got a response: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=220093&tstart=0  Hope that helps :)